# Caffe to CoreML Model Conversion

Tags: caffe, coreml

I have downloaded a model from the given link
http://posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu/OpenPose/models/hand/pose_iter_102000.caffemodel

Then i use this Python code to convert this model into .mlmodel

import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert('pose_iter_102000.caffemodel','pose_deploy.prototxt')
coremltools.utils.save_spec(coreml_model, 'my_model.mlmodel')

After compiling this code error is something like this

================= Starting Conversion from Caffe to CoreML ======================
Layer 0: Type: 'CPMData', Name: 'data'. Output(s): 'data', 'label'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ModelConversionFile.py", line 2, in 
    coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert('pose_iter_102000.caffemodel','pose_deploy.prototxt')
  File "/Users/tahirhameed/Desktop/NewPythonTest/MyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/caffe/_caffe_converter.py", line 191, in convert
    predicted_feature_name)
  File "/Users/tahirhameed/Desktop/NewPythonTest/MyEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/caffe/_caffe_converter.py", line 255, in _export
    predicted_feature_name)
RuntimeError: Cannot convert caffe layer of type 'CPMData'.

Answer (score 0):

The model you are trying to convert is containing a layer type (`CPMData`) that is not supported by CoreML. You would need to [provide an implementation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/core_ml_api/creating_a_custom_layer) for that layer yourself.

Comment: Let me try this first

Comment: New error is below, can you guide me regarding this

Using PyCharm

Your compilation was sucessful, but please file a radar on Core ML | Neural Networks and attach the model that generated this message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/HandModeltoCoreML.py", line 16, in <module>
    coreml_model.input_description['data'] = 'Input image to be classified'
  File "model.py", line 79, in __setitem__
    raise AttributeError("No feature with name %s." % key)
AttributeError: No feature with name data.

Comment: Huh, difficult… It seems there's something off with your model topology. It's looking for a feature (think intermediate data buffer) with the name "data" and can't find it. It seems this is supposed to be the input of the model, but it's somehow missing from the actual model structure.